# Foreman aborting during development because of delayed_job reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, foreman

I'm using foreman to run my server and a delayed job process locally for my development environment.

Delayed job is automatically reloading my code periodically and if I've made a syntax error in my code the delayed job process is exiting and causing foreman to stop all other processes too. This means if I save a file with an error in my development environment stops.

The key lines from the stack trace are (I believe):

```
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | rake aborted!
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | SyntaxError: /home/james/dev/myproject/app/helpers/icon_helper.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
...
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@mygemset/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@mygemset/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/worker.rb:298:in `reload!'
...
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | Tasks: TOP => jobs:work
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
17:22:18 delayed_jobs.1  | exited with code 1
17:22:18 system          | sending SIGTERM to all processes
17:22:18 webserver.1     | Exiting
17:22:18 webserver.1     | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I know I can stop delayed_job from reloading with `config.cache_classes = false` but I'd like that to be true so that my webserver reloads classes each request.

I'd *like* for delayed_job to be reloading my classes too. Is there a way for delayed job to try to reload but keep running if the reload fails? If not, is there a different way to turn off reloading for delayed job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague suggested wrapping delayed job in a script that just restarts it if it exits unexpectedly (in `myproject/script/delayed_job.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    bundle exec rake jobs:work
    echo 'Delayed jobs quit... restarting in 5s'
    sleep 5
done
```

The in the Procfile:

```
delayed_jobs: script/delayed_jobs.sh
```

This script does the job we need.